# Shipping Charges Program Error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, jgrasp

```
 if(weight <= 2)
  {
     charges=miles*1.10;
  }   
  else if(weight > 2 && weight <= 6);
  {
     charges=miles*2.20;
  }
  else if(weight > 6 && weight <= 10);
  {
     charges=miles*3.37;
  }   
  else if(weight > 10 && weight <= 20);
  {
     charges=miles*2.80;   
  }
```

This is just part of it but I keep receiving the following error message:

```
ShippingAssign.java:32: 'else' without 'if'
  else if(weight > 6 && weight <= 10);
  ^
ShippingAssign.java:36: 'else' without 'if'
  else if(weight > 10 && weight <= 20);
  ^
2 errors

----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Any idea as in to what I could be doing wrong? I felt like I understood what was being asked of me but clearly I am making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` after every `else if`.

```
else if(weight > 2 && weight <= 6);
                ------------------^
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I overlooked that mistake!

Comment: @JavaNewb no issue dear,it can happen with anyone.If is work thn select it as correct answer